# How can I prevent a conflict between JSON encode and a unique id generator?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to insert a unique id into my database and output some text via json encode. Like this my code is working fine, my output is "hello":

```
   $json = array(
        'example' => 'hello',
    );

   echo json_encode($json);

   $uniqueID = "123";

   $pdo = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO example (unique_id) values(:unique_id) ');
    $pdo->execute(array(
        ':unique_id' => $uniqueID,
    ));
```

But when I want to generate the unique id, then there is some error I cannot figure out:

```
   $json = array(
        'example' => 'hello',
    );

   echo json_encode($json);

   $random_id_length = 10; 
   $uniqueID = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1)); 
   $uniqueID = strip_tags(stripslashes($uniqueID)); 
   $uniqueID = str_replace(".","",$uniqueID); 
   $uniqueID = strrev(str_replace("/","",$uniqueID)); 
   $uniqueID = substr($uniqueID,0,$random_id_length); 

   $pdo = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO example (unique_id) values(:unique_id) ');
    $pdo->execute(array(
        ':unique_id' => $uniqueID,
    ));
```

Like this, everything is correctly inserted into the database. But I do not get any output.

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: I do not get any error message, just a blank page

Comment: But the error is already caused when I use only line `$uniqueID = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1))`

Comment: have you checked the error log for anything? You say it inserts, so it must be running the execute. By that logic it should have printed the json to screen

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with error log, but I do not see any error output

Comment: Yes, the insert is working fine

Comment: dependent on environment settings the error may be logged to a file, instead of to screen. Check to find the default log file and see if an error is there. Does it insert anything into `unique_id`?

Comment: are you getting the output of echo $uniqueID; before DB Insert action..?

Comment: @ThePlusProgrammer I want to output only "hello". And it actually works when I do not use `substr` or `crypt` and `str_replace` and so on

Comment: @atoms Yes, the uniqueID is inserted correctly into the database. Just the output of `hello` is not working.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I found out that the error is exactly in this line `$uniqueID = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1)); ` If I change it to `$uniqueID = uniqid(rand(),1);` then it is working

Comment: @Jarla, your code is working fine without any changes on my system with your Output hello. I Don't thinks your code is creating any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the error that you're getting is this:

```
PHP: crypt(): No salt parameter was specified. You must use a randomly generated salt and a strong hash function to produce a secure hash.
```

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php):

> The salt parameter is optional. However, crypt() creates a weak hash without the salt. PHP 5.6 or later raise an E_NOTICE error without it. Make sure to specify a strong enough salt for better security.

The [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) also recommend using [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead:

> password_hash() uses a strong hash, generates a strong salt, and applies proper rounds automatically. password_hash() is a simple crypt() wrapper and compatible with existing password hashes. Use of password_hash() is encouraged.

So try changing:

```
$uniqueID = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1));
```

To:

```
$uniqueID = password_hash(uniqid(rand(),1), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: I tested it, but unfortunately still no output

Comment: The problem was exactly that line. It worked, when I changed it to `$uniqueID = uniqid(rand(),1);`